# How to constrain dimension in uncosntrained array when 1st is already constrained?

Tags: vhdl

With VHDL 2008, you are allowed to define unconstrained types/subtypes. For example:

```vhdl
slv_array_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
```

then you can create subtypes where one or more dimensions is left open to be constrained later.

```vhdl
subtype slv32_array_t is slv_array_t(open)(31 downto 0);
signal some_object  : slv32_array_t(7 downto 0);
```

This is fine when the `open` dimensions are the first ones. But how can I constrain a subtype if the unconstrained dimension is not the first one? The following gives the error inn ActiveHDL that the dimension is already constrained.

`Index constraint cannot be applied to constrained type.`

```vhdl
subtype slv_array8_t is slv_array_t(7 downto 0)(open);  -- legal
signal some_object : slv_array8_t(31 downto 0);
```

The following also compains with the same error:

```vhdl
signal some_object : slv_array8_t(7 downto 0)(31 downto 0);
```

So, is there actually a way this type can be constrained in an object with VHDL 2008? Did it even make it into VHDL 2019?

Comment: `signal some_object: slv_array8_t(open)(31 downto 0);` There's an example at the end of 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General, a variable declaration. The semantics are described in 
5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `(open)` to "jump over" the constrained dimension, just like you did with the `subtype`:

```
signal some_object : slv_array8_t(open)(31 downto 0);
```

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity E is
end entity E;

architecture A of E is
  type slv_array_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
  subtype slv32_array_t is slv_array_t(open)(31 downto 0);
  signal some_object  : slv32_array_t(7 downto 0);
  subtype slv_array8_t is slv_array_t(7 downto 0)(open);  -- legal
  signal some_object2 : slv_array8_t(open)(31 downto 0);
begin
end architecture A;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/reNU

Comment: I called the entity `tricky`, the architecture `no_mcve` and used ghdl.

Comment: The empowering mechanism for your 'jump over' is found in 6.3 Subtype declaration "A subtype indication defines a subtype of the base type of the type mark."

Comment: Why didnt I try this? @user1155120 I even had that page of the LRM open :facepalm